# how to create a column with datatype 'TimeStampWithTimezone' in sails.js v1.0.2 models?

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I'm using sails v 1.0.2 and sails-PostgreSQL adapter. I have a model that has a column of date type that saves current time in the format of timestamp with time zone. how should I do it? previously I created my database in pgAdmin statically but now I don't know how to do it in sails

Comment: I recommend storing the data as a js timestamp as a number and using [momentjs-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to handle it once retrieved.

Comment: To clarify above, the number is what's stored in the db, but moment-js can be used to help make calculations or format it when you need to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but in case anyone else comes across this question, here's how you do it:

```js
dateField: {
    type: 'ref',
    columnType: 'timestamptz'
}
```